# Get current logged in user in provider hosted app

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, provider-hosted-app

I have to get current logged in user in provider hosted app event receiver.

I used the below code to get the current user name, but I got current user name as Sharepoint App instead of Current logged in user.

```
currentUser = clientContext.Web.CurrentUser;
clientContext.Load(currentUser, x => x.LoginName, y => y.Id);
clientContext.Load(currentUser, Z => Z.Title);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

How to get the current logged in user?

Comment: is this app-only context ?

Comment: yes this is app only context

Answer (score 3):

If you are using app only context in your provider hosted app then you need to do a li'l extra work and use TokenHelper to get appOnlyAccessToken. On App's page load, just run the below script:

```
var contextTokenString = TokenHelper.GetContextTokenFromRequest(Page.Request);
Uri sharepointUrl = new Uri(Request.QueryString["SPHostUrl"]);
SharePointContextToken contextToken = TokenHelper.ReadAndValidateContextToken(contextTokenString, Request.Url.Authority);
string appOnlyAccessToken = TokenHelper.GetAppOnlyAccessToken(contextToken.TargetPrincipalName, sharepointUrl.Authority, contextToken.Realm).AccessToken;
using (var clientContext = TokenHelper.GetClientContextWithAccessToken(sharepointUrl.ToString(), appOnlyAccessToken))
            {
                var currentUser = clientContext.Web.CurrentUser;                
                clientContext.Load(currentUser);                              
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                // TODO: display logged in user however you want
            }
```

Well, I am your savior today. You can thank me later! :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply .but i am using remote event receiver.If i use this code in .svc file it shows error in Page.Request